# Who does the relative pronoun THAT represent?

Tags: relative-pronouns

**1.*Organizational structure refers to the formalized patterns of interactions that link a firm's tasks,technologies, and people.***

**2.*Organizational structure refers to the formalized patterns of the interactions that link a firm's tasks,technologies, and people.***

Do the two sentences have same meanings? In the two sentences,the relative pronoun*That* represent whom, is it *patterns* or *interactions*? I'm confused about the rule- relative pronoun represents the noun/pronoun just before it. I belive, in the first sentence, THAT represent THE FORMALIZED PATTERNS (specifically PATTERNS), and in the second sentence, THAT represents THE INTERACTIONS, is it correct?

Can I rewrite the first sentance in the following way?

--Organizational structure refers to the interaction's formalized patterns that link a firm's tasks,technologies, and people.

In this sentence,  the relative pronoun *that* represents the noun *patterns*, but not instructions, doesn't it?

Comment: The only difference between your two sentences it the addition of *the* in the second sentence. I fail to see how you are comparing the two when your focus is on the use of *that*, which exists in both. In other words, your question isn't represented by the examples you chose.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a hard sentence to parse. ***That*** is introducing a restrictive clause, meaning it's important to know the antecedent of *that*. The second version has, I think, only one parse - where *that* refers to *interactions*. Without that definite article, *that* may refer to *interactions*, or to *formalised patterns of interactions*. This is because "formalised patterns of interactions" is a noun phrase in itself, so it can be the antecedent of a relative pronoun.

Your rewrite doesn't work in either case, not least because the genitive *-'s* can't always be used to substitute for a genitive *of*. However, the fact that the *that* changes antecedent is a big part of it - you are now saying it's the patterns that link, which is a complete change of meaning if the antecedent of *that* was *interactions*, and still a change of meaning if the antecedent was *formalised patterns of interactions*.

Plus you changed *interactions* from plural to singular in that rewrite.

Comment: If *a cricket player =a player of cricket*, then why not *the formalized patterns of interections=the interections' formalized patterns*? why does the second rewriting have the differenet meaning from its original, although first one has not.